# All data in a row. Move observations under each other

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
data <- list(list(eventId = 8, subEventName = "Simple pass", tags = list(
  list(id = 1801)), playerId = 122671, positions = list(list(
    y = 50, x = 50), list(y = 53, x = 35)), matchId = 2057954, 
  eventName = "Pass", teamId = 16521, matchPeriod = "1H", eventSec = 1.656214, 
  subEventId = 85, id = 258612104), list(eventId = 8, subEventName = "High pass", 
                                         tags = list(list(id = 1801)), playerId = 139393, positions = list(
                                           list(y = 53, x = 35), list(y = 19, x = 75)), matchId = 2057954, 
                                         eventName = "Pass", teamId = 16521, matchPeriod = "1H", eventSec = 4.487814, 
                                         subEventId = 83, id = 258612106))
```

I want to create a data frame out of this list. I use `unlist(data)`, which creates a row with repeated variables.

```
> unlist(data)
      eventId  subEventName       tags.id      playerId   positions.y   positions.x   positions.y 
          "8" "Simple pass"        "1801"      "122671"          "50"          "50"          "53" 
  positions.x       matchId     eventName        teamId   matchPeriod      eventSec    subEventId 
         "35"     "2057954"        "Pass"       "16521"          "1H"    "1.656214"          "85" 
           id       eventId  subEventName       tags.id      playerId   positions.y   positions.x 
  "258612104"           "8"   "High pass"        "1801"      "139393"          "53"          "35" 
  positions.y   positions.x       matchId     eventName        teamId   matchPeriod      eventSec 
         "19"          "75"     "2057954"        "Pass"       "16521"          "1H"    "4.487814" 
   subEventId            id 
         "83"   "258612106"
```

Each observation starts with the `eventId` variable. So, basically I have to split the data into dataframes starting with `eventId`, and then moving those dataframes one under the other. I.e. having two observations in this case. Do you have any idea?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tibblify--

```
library(tibblify)

tibblify(data)
## A tibble: 2 x 12
#  eventId subEventName               tags playerId          positions matchId eventName teamId matchPeriod eventSec subEventId        id
#    <dbl> <chr>        <list<tbl_df[,1]>>    <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,2]>>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1       8 Simple pass             [1 x 1]   122671            [2 x 2] 2057954 Pass       16521 1H              1.66         85 258612104
#2       8 High pass               [1 x 1]   139393            [2 x 2] 2057954 Pass       16521 1H              4.49         83 258612106
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` :

```
result <- data.table::rbindlist(data)
result

#   eventId subEventName      tags playerId positions matchId eventName teamId matchPeriod eventSec subEventId       id
#1:       8  Simple pass <list[1]>   122671 <list[2]> 2057954      Pass  16521          1H     1.66         85 2.59e+08
#2:       8  Simple pass <list[1]>   122671 <list[2]> 2057954      Pass  16521          1H     1.66         85 2.59e+08
#3:       8    High pass <list[1]>   139393 <list[2]> 2057954      Pass  16521          1H     4.49         83 2.59e+08
#4:       8    High pass <list[1]>   139393 <list[2]> 2057954      Pass  16521          1H     4.49         83 2.59e+08
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help solve your problem?

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), nrow=length(data), byrow=T))
```

Comment: this formula does not work for this data:

 list(list(eventId = 8, subEventName = "Simple pass", tags = list(
    list(id = 1801)), playerId = 122671, positions = list(list(
    y = 50, x = 50), list(y = 53, x = 35)), matchId = 2057954, 
    eventName = "Pass", teamId = 16521, matchPeriod = "1H", eventSec = 1.656214, 
    subEventId = 85, id = 258612104), list(eventId = 8, subEventName = "High pass",

Comment: tags = list(list(id = 1801)), playerId = 139393, positions = list(
        list(y = 53, x = 35), list(y = 19, x = 75)), matchId = 2057954, 
    eventName = "Pass", teamId = 16521, matchPeriod = "1H", eventSec = 4.487814, 
    subEventId = 83, id = 258612106), list(eventId = 1, subEventName = "Air duel", 
    tags = list(list(id = 703), list(id = 1801)), playerId = 103668, 
    positions = list(list(y = 81, x = 25), list(y = 83, x = 37)), 
    matchId = 2057954, eventName = "Duel", teamId = 14358, matchPeriod = "1H", 
    eventSec = 5.937411, subEventId = 10, id = 258612077))

Comment: P.S: in list element 3 the sublist tags hs 2 elements unlike in the first two cases